# Where does SqlMembershipProvider store access roles?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have membership provider database includes a set of `aspnet_Membership` tables.

I'm trying to add some access rule to the application.

(1) In `web.config` e.g.

```
<location path='..'>...<allow roles='admin'>..</location>
```

(2) or through the `Web Site Administration Tool >> Manage Access rules`?

Both of them can work.

Where are the rules created in (2) stored ? I cannot find them in the database.

I suppose (1) and (2) are setting rules in different level.

Which way should I use, regarding security and functionality.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both 1 and 2 methods are stored in same Web.config. You need to click ***Show All Files***.

[image]

Comment: Thx, where is the "Show All Files"?? I cannot see my webconfig change, If I create rules in Web Site Administration Tool.

Comment: Editing the web.config manually is much easier than Web Site Administration Tool.

Comment: KK. I found another web.config in a sub folder. I'm going to integrate them and make an external one for all the rules, thx!